# Add Update and Delete Item from Listview on Server Response Dynamically

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

Hi I don't know asking proper question or not but i want to develop Like Comment on Facebook post, Update comment and Delete Comment.

When i will add comment it will send request to server and it will give response with new values to fill in listadapter and that change may appear on my listview after click on enter or add button, and on delete it will send request to server and in response fill my listAdapter. and change may appear on my listview without refreshing listview. how can i perform this operation .

Thank You in Adavance.

**Here is my Class.**

```
public class CommmentActivity extends Activity{



DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
List<CommentListInfo> list_CommentInfo = new ArrayList<CommentListInfo>();
List<String> SuggetionList;
AutoCompleteTextView aCompletView;
EditText etComment;
String strComment;
ArrayAdapter<String> mentionList;
ListCommentAdapter commentAdapter;
ImageView IvAddComment;
ListView CommentList;
SessionCreator m_session;
boolean m = false;

boolean mBuzy;

int FirstPosition;
int ItemCounted;
int CurrentScrollState;
int TotalItemCount;

String UserId;
String VidoId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.commentvideo_main);


    SuggetionList =  new ArrayList<String>();
    String Curl = GlobalMethod.TokenGenerator() + "&action=getCommentsVideo";

    Intent data = getIntent();
    UserId = data.getStringExtra("userId");
    VidoId = data.getStringExtra("videoId");
    init();

    String strfriendsSyncDate = m_session.getfriendsSyncDate();

    Log.d("mData", strfriendsSyncDate);




    new CommentsDetail().execute(UserId,VidoId,strfriendsSyncDate,Curl,"1");


    commentAdapter = new ListCommentAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list_CommentInfo);
        CommentList.setAdapter(commentAdapter); 

    CommentList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (scrollState) {
            case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:{
                commentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //ManipulateVisibleView(view);
                break;
            }

            case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
            {
                mBuzy = true;
                break;
            }

            case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING:{
                mBuzy = true;
                break;
            }


            default:
                break;
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FirstPosition = firstVisibleItem;
            ItemCounted = visibleItemCount;
            TotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            int LastPosition = view.getLastVisiblePosition();
            Log.d("First Position", ""+FirstPosition);
            Log.d("ItemCountes",""+ItemCounted);
            Log.d("totalItemCount",""+TotalItemCount);
            Log.d("LastPosition",""+LastPosition);


            if(visibleItemCount!=0 && ((firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount)>=(totalItemCount))){

            Log.d("mCalled", "call");
            }
        isScrollCompleted();
        }
    });



IvAddComment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            strComment = etComment.getText().toString();
            etComment.getText().clear();
            String strUrl = GlobalMethod.TokenGenerator() + "&action=addCommentsVideo";

            new CommentsDetail().execute(UserId,VidoId,strComment,strUrl,"0");
            commentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });



}
private void isScrollCompleted(){
if(this.ItemCounted >0 && this.CurrentScrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
    Log.d("ItemCounted",""+ItemCounted);
    Log.d("CurrentScrollState",""+CurrentScrollState);
}   
}

private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    m_session = new SessionCreator(getApplicationContext());
    etComment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etComments);
    CommentList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvLatestComments);
    IvAddComment = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.addComment);
}

public class CommentsDetail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ServiceHandler serviceClient;
        String mJsonString;

        try{

            String userId = (String)params[0];
            String vId = (String)params[1];
            if(params[4].equals("0")){


                String comment = (String)params[2];
                String strUrl = (String)params[3];

                List<NameValuePair> paramsNameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                paramsNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", userId));
                paramsNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("videoId", vId));
                paramsNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("commentText", comment));

                serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
                mJsonString = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(strUrl,
                        ServiceHandler.POST, paramsNameValuePairs);

                Log.i("---->>>>>>>>>>", paramsNameValuePairs + "");
            }else{

                String syncdate = (String)params[2];
                String strUrl = (String)params[3];

                List<NameValuePair> paramsNameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                paramsNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", userId));
                paramsNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("videoId", vId));
                paramsNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("friendsSyncDate", syncdate));

                serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
                mJsonString = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(strUrl,
                        ServiceHandler.POST, paramsNameValuePairs);

                Log.i("---->>>>>>>>>>", paramsNameValuePairs + "");
            }



        Log.d("Response Json-----------------------",mJsonString );


        return mJsonString;

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unchecked", "unchecked" })
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        try{
        if (result != null) {
            JSONObject responsJsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) responsJsonObj
                    .optJSONObject("data");

            try {
                String str = jsonObj.getString("error");
                if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                    // error
                    //Toast.makeText(NewsfeedActivity.this, jsonObj.getString("error"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                Log.d("jex ------>", "" + je.getMessage());
                try {
                    String str = jsonObj.getString("message");
                    Log.d("message=", "" + str);
                    if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                        // VALID RESPONSE, NOW PARSE IT
                        if (jsonObj.has("comments")) {
                            JSONArray colArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("comments");
                            Log.d("Colunm Array", ""+colArray);
                            int nComments = colArray.length();
                            Log.d("# comments", "" + nComments);
                            for(int i=0; i<nComments; i++){
                                JSONObject obj = colArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Gson Comments = new Gson();
                                String strComments = Comments.toJson(obj);
                                Log.d("# obj=", "" + obj.toString());               
                                CommentListInfo cmtInfo = new CommentListInfo();                
                                cmtInfo.c_userId = obj.getString("userId");
                                cmtInfo.c_name = obj.getString("name");
                                cmtInfo.DateAdded = obj.getString("dateAdded");
                                cmtInfo.CommentId = obj.getString("commentId");
                                cmtInfo.CommentText = obj.getString("text");
                                cmtInfo.ImageUrl = obj.getString("imageLink");
                                list_CommentInfo.add(cmtInfo);  
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                        // VALID RESPONSE, NOW PARSE IT
                        if (jsonObj.has("addPosition")) {
                                Log.d("# obj=", "" + jsonObj.toString());   
                                Log.d("Add Position", jsonObj.getString("addPosition"));
                        }
                    }

//                      
                    if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                        // VALID RESPONSE, NOW PARSE IT
                        if (jsonObj.has("friendsSyncDate")) {
                            Log.d("# friendsDeleted", "" + jsonObj);
                                Log.d("# obj=", "" + jsonObj.toString());   

                                String myString = m_session.getfriendsSyncDate();
                                Log.d("myString", myString);

                                m_session.putfriendsSyncDate(jsonObj.getString("friendsSyncDate"));
                                Log.d("Sync Date "," "+jsonObj.getString("friendsSyncDate"));
                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException je2) {
                    je2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

   }

 }
```

**Here is my Adapter Class.**

```
public class ListCommentAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context mContext;
private List<CommentListInfo> CommentsInfo;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private String szUserId;
private String szVideoID;

private boolean mBuzy = false;



public ListCommentAdapter(Context context, List<CommentListInfo> cmtInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mContext = context;
    CommentsInfo = cmtInfo;
    AppData mmap = (AppData)this.mContext.getApplicationContext();
    szUserId = mmap.getUserId();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return CommentsInfo.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return CommentsInfo.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder = new Holder();


    CommentListInfo c = CommentsInfo.get(position);


    try{

        Log.i("nUserId", c.c_userId);
        Log.i("nName", c.c_name);
        Log.i("nCommentId", c.CommentId);
        Log.i("nCommnet", c.CommentText);
        Log.i("nImageUrl",c.ImageUrl);

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Erore is",""+e);
    }


    try{
            if(inflater==null){
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            if(convertView==null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_list_item, null);
                holder.ciProfileImage = (CircleImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.civCFLeftPic);
                holder.tvComments = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCommentbox);
                holder.tvCDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCfNotifyDate);
                holder.tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCommentName);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();
            }


            if(!mBuzy){

                RemoteImageLoader task = new RemoteImageLoader();
                task.setImageView(holder.ciProfileImage);
                task.execute(c.ImageUrl);

                Log.d("ImagerUrl", c.ImageUrl);
                if(c.ImageUrl!=null){
                    Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.world1)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.world1)
                    .error(R.drawable.world1)
                    .into(holder.ciProfileImage);

                }else{
                    Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.world1)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.world1)
                    .error(R.drawable.world1)
                    .into(holder.ciProfileImage);
                }
            holder.tvComments.setText(c.CommentText);
            holder.tvCDate.setText(c.DateAdded);
            holder.tvName.setText(c.c_name);
            holder.tvComments.setTag(null);

            }else{
                holder.tvComments.setText("Loading...");
                holder.tvComments.setTag(this);
            }

            return convertView;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error IS :- "+ e);
        }

    return convertView;
}

private static class Holder{
    private TextView tvName,tvComments,tvCDate;
    private CircleImageView ciProfileImage;     
 }
}
```

Comment: Add your code.What have you tried?

Comment: @ajit i have add my code

Comment: You have to use the onclick listener on yours Adapter class and delete the items on the basis of position of getView method..

Comment: What about to add new item and update item. that makes confused me.@RavindraKushwaha

Comment: Either you are adding the items or getting the numbers of items from web service there is no effect to use the onclick listener inside yours getView method and delete the items according position of getView method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have solved this already but I was working on a different app in Java and came across something similar. Mine was a bit simpler because I am using a local database but ~same thing. In your **CommmentActivity's onCreate** method pull out the  commentAdapter declaration and the CommentList.setOnScrollListener and put them in their own method. Then call your newly defined commentAdapter method in onCreate and after you parse through the response.
 Something like this

```
public void myAdaperMethod(Context context, List<CommentListInfo>      list_CommentInfo){
commentAdapter = new ListCommentAdapter(this, list_CommentInfo);
CommentList.setAdapter(commentAdapter);
CommentList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){...}
}

onCreate{
myAdapterMethod(...);
}

post{...}
get{myAdapterMethod(...);}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to re-bind your control after the listadapter has the new dataset.

CommentList.DataBind();

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the code at first, and I when I see c syntax I always go back to C#.

Comment: how i will implement this solution.?